# Is it possible to route a block of public IPs to an EC2 instance?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, proxy, amazon-vpc, http-proxy

I am trying to associate a pool of public proxies (1,024) to an EC2 instance on AWS. This EC2 instance is setup with squid proxy to forward all of my http requests. The goal is to be able to be able to pass in any of these public IPs to my requests and it will route it to this instance which is communicating with the Internet Gateway. Per AWS documentations https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html, there is a max number of IPs that can be associated to an instance. Is there a way to get around this or somehow leverage a custom route table to get this to work?

Comment: To clarify... you are wanting to associate 1000+ public IP addresses to a single Amazon EC2 instance? Why do you need each proxy to use a different IP address? Could they use the same IP address but just have a different path?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Correct I want to associate 1000+ public IP to a single EC2 instance. This is similar to creating a network of proxy service where I can use a different IPs to scrape different websites.

Comment: This is not possible. You can not use that many ENIs on an instance. Plus, if you want the IP addresses to be static, you would need to use Elastic IP addresses and AWS would not give you 1000 EIPs for this purpose. You will need to change your architecture.